# How to avoid move semantics for class members?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

**Example:**
I have the following code (reduced to model example, Qt library used, Qt classes behavior explained below):

```
struct Test_impl {
  int x;
  Test_impl() : x(0) {}
  Test_impl(int val) : x(val) {}
};

class Test {
  QSharedPointer<Test_impl> m;
public:
  Test() : m(new Test_impl()) {}
  Test(int val) : m(new Test_impl(val)) {}
  void assign(const QVariant& v) {m = v.value<Test>().m; ++m->x;}
  ~Test(){--m->x;}
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Test)
```

`QSharedPointer` is a smart pointer implementing move semantic (which is omitted in documentation). `QVariant` is somewhat similar to `std::any` and has the template method

```
template<typename T> inline T value() const;
```

Macro `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` allows values of type `Test` to be placed inside a `QVariant`.

**Problem:**
Line `m = v.value<Test>().m;` seemingly invokes move assignment for the field `m` of a temporary object returned by `value()`. After that, `Test` destructor is called and promptly crashes trying to access illegal address.
Generally, the problem as I see it is that while move assignment leaves the object itself in a consistent state, state of an object containing moved entity "unexpectedly" changes.

There are several ways to avoid the problem in this particular example I can think of: change `Test` destructor to expect null `m`, write template `template<typename T> inline T no_move(T&& tmp) {return tmp;}`, explicitly create temporary `Test` object in `assign`, add getter for `m` and call it to force copying `m` (advised by [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42)); MS Visual Studio allows to write `std::swap(m, v.value<Test>().m)`, but this code is illegal.

**Question(s):**
Is there a "proper" (best practice?) way to explicitly invoke copy assignment (or somehow properly invoke `swap`) instead of move? Is there a way to prohibit move semantics for class fields used in the destructor? Why moving a temporary object member was made a default option in the first place?

Comment: Declare move constructor as deleted i.e. `Test(Test&&) = delete;`. But fixing your class to allow moving without UB is better.

Comment: (a) I don't think move constructor of `Test` is the problem here (implementing it to force copy changes nothing and described solutions (seemingly) work without messing with it). (b) Deleting it would break `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` (since `QVariant` returns object by value).

Comment: You might also use getter to avoid the move.

Comment: Guessing that `value<Test>()` returns a copy of something, but the `Test` class doesn't have a copy constructor. So what happens there?

Comment: @BoPersson Compiler-generated copy constructor is invoked (as far as I understand). Since it is good enough for `Test` - the only class invariant here is (should be) that `m` is not null - I see no need to redefine it for the example.

Comment: Check the shared pointer in the destructor. It can become a nullptr after a move. Just don't dereference it if it did. OTOH if you want an accurate counter, you do need to define your own copy ctor and copy assignment, and increment it there.

Comment: @n.m. `int` variable is used for the example, actual code is trickier and uses things like `QObject::connect`/`disconnect` (also, redefined copy constructor for `Test`), but I thought this would cloud the problem.

Comment: I don't see why it would matter. A moved-from pointer is a null pointer, whatever it points at.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test {
  QSharedPointer<Test_impl> m;
public:
  Test() : m(new Test_impl()) {}
  Test(int val) : m(new Test_impl(val)) {}
  Test(Test const&)=default;
  Test& operator=(Test const&)=default;
  void assign(const QVariant& v) {
    *this = v.value<Test>();
    ++m->x;
  }
  ~Test(){--m->x;}
};
```

Your code doesn't support move construction, as you want never empty, and moving a QSharedPointer apparently makes it empty.

By explicitly `=default`ing the copy constructor (and assign) we block automatic synthesis of the move constructor (and assignment).

By *not* accessing the fields while they are rvalues, and instead first copying them, we avoid them clearing their own state while the surrounding class expects them to store state.

This should prevent your crash, but doesn't fix your design problem.

---

In general, using a `QSharedPointer` in a way that presumes it cannot be null is bad form.  It is a nullable type, nullable types can be null.

We can fix this by stopping that assumption.  Or we can write a non-nullable shared pointer.

```
template<class T>
struct never_null_shared_ptr:
  private QSharedPointer<T>
{
  using ptr=QSharedPointer<T>;
  template<class...Args>
  never_null_shared_ptr(Args&&...args):
    ptr(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
  {}
  never_null_shared_ptr():
    ptr(new T())
  {}
  template<class...Ts>
  void replace(Ts&&...ts) {
    QSharedPointer<T> tmp(new T(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...));
    // paranoid:
    if (tmp) ((ptr&)*this) = std::move(tmp);
  }
  never_null_shared_ptr(never_null_shared_ptr const&)=default;
  never_null_shared_ptr& operator=(never_null_shared_ptr const&)=default;
  // not never_null_shared_ptr(never_null_shared_ptr&&)
  ~never_null_shared_ptr()=default;
  using ptr::operator*;
  using ptr::operator->;
  // etc
};
```

Simply `using` to import parts of the API of QSharedPointer you want to support and do not permit you to reset the value in the pointer.

Now the type `never_null_shared_ptr` enforces that invariant of it not being empty.

Note that constructin a `never_null_shared_ptr` from a pointer is not advised.  Instead you forward construct it.  If you really need that, you should have it throw if the pointer passed in is null, preventing construction from occurring.  This will also possibly require fancy SFINAE.

In practice, this kind of runtime checking is worse than static checking, so I'd just remove the from-pointer constructor.

Giving us:

```
class Test {
  never_null_shared_ptr<Test_impl> m;
public:
  Test() : m() {}
  Test(int val) : m(val) {}
  void assign(const QVariant& v) {m = v.value<Test>().m; ++m->x;}
  ~Test(){--m->x;}
};
```

In essence, with the substitution of the nullable shared ptr with a non-nullable shared ptr, and replacing `new` calls to placement constructs, your code as written suddenly works.

Comment: "This should prevent your crash, (...)" - it doesn't (I've checked) and I don't understand why it should. `m` of temporary object is still moved, leaving null pointer behind. Also, I take it that your answer to my first two questions is "don't design your class so that you would need to prevent move in the first place"?

Comment: @Abstraction Ah, spotted problem and fixed it.  Note that 2nd answer didn't have this problem; because I folded the invariant into the smart pointer, misuse in the containing class couldn't null it.  The second answer remains the best: if you must have a non-nullable pointer, enforce it with the type system.  If that fails, runtime enforce it with asserts and throws.  Only if that fails mix the enforcement with business logic.  Or have the business logic not assume it is non-nullable.